# Who is index 0 validator in ethereum beacon chain?

Tags: blocks, validators, beacon-chain, slots

Address: 0x933ad9491b62059dd065b560d256d8957a8c402cc6e8d8ee7290ae11e8f7329267a8811c397529dac52ae1342ba58c95

In beaconscan.com, the index 0 validator proposed block nearly 20,000 times and almost proposals were skipped, but it doesn't receive any penalties.

(ref : https://beaconscan.com/validator/0#proposed)

Who is this validator, and why doesn't it receive any penalties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. One thing I found weird on the link *beaconscan* you provided is the sentence:

> Skipped: did not correctly propose within the given time frame (i.e. offline) and **was penalized**

I don't recall having seen anywhere on the protocol a penalty given to an absent proposer. So my answer to your question would be: this validator did not receive penalties for not proposing blocks because no one ever does.

But I also wonder who would skip `20070` chances to propose a block...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the beaconscan.com is incorrect, because other scanning site like beaconcha.in show different informations about index 0 validator (https://beaconcha.in/validator/933ad9491b62059dd065b560d256d8957a8c402cc6e8d8ee7290ae11e8f7329267a8811c397529dac52ae1342ba58c95), so I think I need to download the beacon chain and check it out